# Unexplained discrepancies when copying and modifying std::strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, copy-constructor

In the following code, *"situation 1"*  works as expected on all
compilers tested, however *"situation 2"* it seems to behave differently
based on the compiler used.

As an example MSVC has sit1 and sit2 produce the same results, however
when using gcc/clang and libstdc++, the modification occurs to the
original string and it's copy *(sort of like a COW string)* even though
I'm building using the C++11 switch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

   // situation 1
   {
      std::string x0 = "12345678";
      std::string x1 = x0;

      char* ptr = &x0[0] + 3;

      (*ptr) = ' ';

      std::cout << "1. x0: " << x0 << "\n";
      std::cout << "1. x1: " << x1 << "\n";

      if ((&x0[0]) == x0.data()) std::cout << "1. ptrs are equal\n";

   }

   // situation 2
   {
      std::string x0 = "12345678";
      std::string x1 = x0;

      char* ptr = const_cast<char*>(x0.data() + 3);

      (*ptr) = ' ';

      std::cout << "2. x0: " << x0 << "\n";
      std::cout << "2. x1: " << x1 << "\n";

      if ((&x0[0]) == x0.data()) std::cout << "2. ptrs are equal\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

GCC (6.1)

```
1. x0: 123 5678
1. x1: 12345678
1. ptrs are equal
2. x0: 123 5678
2. x1: 123 5678
2. ptrs are equal
```

MSVC (2015)

```
1. x0: 123 5678
1. x1: 12345678
1. ptrs are equal
2. x0: 123 5678
2. x1: 12345678
2. ptrs are equal
```

Is there any reason for the discrepancies in behavior between the various compilers - given that &x0[0] and .data() return the same address?

Comment: [This GCC 6.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cJZq0ey2qv526sJU) behaves correctly.

Comment: Did you really have to replace `4` with `Z`? Could you not find something that's even harder to distinguish visually, like `l` and `I`? Half the fun of asking questions on SO is making it as hard as possible for anyone to spot the important details.

Comment: I really hope you're asking this because you're porting ancient, horrible code you didn't write yourself.

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't realize that, it was just a simple test case.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I found it while investigating a bug, the bug occurred only on linux builds but worked fine with windows builds.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the following gives a different result: http://cpp.sh/32ip  is this really a compiler issue or a difference in the standard libraries?

Comment: @JacobiJohn: It's the standard library. The thing that implements `std::string` :-)

Comment: If you cast the pointers to `uintptr_t` and print them out, you will see that `x1.data()` and `x1.data()` are different.  `ptr` is pointing to somewhere in `x0` in situation 1 and `x1` in situation 2.  Definitely some interaction between UB and CoW.

Comment: In C++1z (hopefully z==7), you'll be able to do this without the const_cast (just like with vector).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Situation 2 causes undefined behaviour:

```
char* ptr = const_cast<char*>(x0.data() + 3);

(*ptr) = 'Z';
```

According to the specification of `std::basic_string::data` (C++14 [string.accessors]/3):

> *Requires:* The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

In other words, you are not allowed to cast away the `const` and modify the string via the pointers returned by `data()` or `c_str()` .

Comment: but the pointer addresses are the same? and doesn't the standard say that x0.data() and &x0[0] should be the same?

Comment: @JacobiJohn they should be the same address, however you are allowed to modify only via the `&x[0]` version.  For a copy-on-write implementation , the `operator[]` will do a copy in case the result is modified, but `.data()` won't.

Comment: @M.M Modifiable, not modified. There's no way for the code to know whether it will actually be modified. In other words, `x[0]` on a non-const string instance/reference already causes the copy, even if nothing further is done with the result.

Comment: That's interesting, how will the std::string class know I've modified it's contents when I access it via a pointer based on &x[0]? As far as I can tell the type of &x[0] is char* which doesnt have any smarts in it like a shared_ptr.

Comment: @SebastianRedl that's what I said

Comment: @JacobiJohn the copy happens when you do `[0]`, not when you actually write

Comment: @M.M So what you're saying is that everytime the non-const subscript operator for std::string is accessed, an if-statement is executed to see if the backing data is aliased and if so it performs a malloc/copy? then returns the value?

Comment: @JacobiJohn: Yes, that's the only way to implement a COW string afaik. Whenever a write could occur, you need to actually make the copy if you didn't already.

Comment: @JacobiJohn in a copy-on-write string, yes that is how it works.

Comment: I believe when OP is comparing the two pointers, the const version of `operator[]` is used.

Comment: @LukeLee `x0` is not `const`, so the non-const version is used